# Cloud composer: Unable to view Admin menu in airflow UI even after rbac=True & rbac_user_registration_code=Op

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-webserver

I am setting up a composer environment,

I have this IAM access: Composer Adminstator

I have marked rbac=True & rbac_user_registration_code=Op

but I am unable to see admin menu in airflow UI & also if I go to my profile in airflow UI it shows the user role as 'Viewer'.

May I know  if I need to add Op/admin role anywhere else to be able to see it in menu.

Answer (score 1):

The `Composer Administrator` [role](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control#permissions) is unrelated to the permissions in the Airflow UI. You need to change your role for the UI to `Admin`, e.g. like so [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/airflow-rbac#registering-users)

Comment: thanks, was going nuts trying to figure this out